# Singleton/Synchronization in Clustered environment

Tags: java, design-patterns, synchronization, singleton, distributed-system

How to achieve singleton instance in clustered environment or how can we have a synchronization of a method in clustered environment using in-memory cache like Redis.

Comment: Some of these distributed caching systems have distributed locks or support compute services that can be guaranteed singletons on cluster. That should be some of the ways to do it...

Comment: @Yathish could you pls tell how redis relates here??

Comment: I just took redis as an example to understand how synchronization can be achieved in distributed environemnt,  it can be any in-memory cache.